# Using SQLCompare to compare a project to other DBs

Tags: redgate, sqlcompare

I'm trying to compare some project that I have in RedGate using SQLCompare. I know that using this command:

`sqlcompare /Project:"E:\XYZ\Project.sdc"`

Will compare the default DBs. I want to compare several databases with that project, I know that I could create several projects and save them with different names and later using the command for each project, but I want to do this in a better way.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As well as specifying a pre-saved project file as the input parameter to the sqlcompare.exe command line, you can also choose to specify the connection details and options as individual switches. This is describe in more detail in this [blog post by Feodor Georgiev](https://www.red-gate.com/blog/sql-compare-command-line-2).

Some switches can be used in conjunction with /project.

For example:
sqlcompare.exe /project:myproject.scp /server2:mytargetserver\instance /db2:mytargetdatabase

In this example the additional /server2 and /db2 switches will override the target server and database saved in the .scp or .sdc project file.